# How to get clicked object in eclipse plugin development using RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to plugin development using eclipse with RCP and Java. I am developing a plugin for a email Client software.

I am trying to find users clicks on target platform, whether it is clicked on texts or hyperlinks using my plugin code.

As of now, I am getting the clicked object as follows,

```
    IWorkbenchPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                            .getActivePage().getActivePart()

    ISelection selection = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection();
                System.out.println(selection .toString());
```

But this shows only same thing for all the clicks even though it is text or links.

Can anyone assist here on how to differentiate these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very unclear - how are you getting from a workbench part to JSON? Is this an editor? Is it your editor?

Comment: How is this code related to the question? Where is it trying to see what has been clicked?

Comment: Really sorry @greg-449, I updated my question and in top sample part of code, I tried to read the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection returned by the part selection provider gives you the selected object in whatever model the current part is using. So if the part is showing a list of files the selection might be the file.

The selection does not tell you anything about the UI the part is using or what caused the selection to happen.

Eclipse does not provide a general API to determine what happened to cause the selection. Some individual parts may provide a specialized API but this is not common.

Comment: The only place I answer questions is here on Stack Overflow (and some other Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: As I said I only answer questions here. There is no email address in my Profile because I do not want to contacted.